# Prove a set of semidirect products are pairwise nonisomorphic

Tags: group-theory

For each homomorphism $\phi:\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\to\text{Aut}(\mathbf{Z}/8\mathbf{Z})$, describe the semidirect product $(\mathbf{Z}/8\mathbf{Z}) \rtimes_\phi (\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$. Prove that these groups are pairwise nonisomorphic.

**My attempt**

For $1\neq x\in \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, $|\phi(x)|$ is either $1$ or $2$. If $\phi(x) = 1$ then the semidirect product is in fact a direct product.

If $\phi(x) = 2$, then $\phi(x)$, viewed as an element in $S_8$, can have cyclic decomposition being the product of one, two, or three disjoint two-cycles. Then one can write out these possibilities explicitly and that would give full descriptions for the possible semidirect products.

**My questions**

First, is my above reasoning correct?

Second, how to show that these semidirect products are pairwise nonisomorphic? I can see that the direct product is certainly nonisomorphic to any of the semidirect products since it is abelian and none of the semidirect products is. But I can't see how the semidirect products can be shown to be pairwise nonisomorphic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A hint is to first determine the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.  A generator of a cyclic group must be mapped to another generator.